# get the current stencil in shapes window c# visio

Tags: visio

In shapes window, how do I get the current stencil file name in shapes window? For example, I choose More Shape-> General ->Basic Shapes (actually basic_m.vssx). Then the shapes are displayed in the shape window. Then I want to know that the file is "basic_m.vssx".

I`m using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application (C#), but I haven`t find the useful function or members that could help.

Help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open a stencil in this way it is just another document but a different type.

You can find the stencils like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= docs.Count; i++)
{
    var doc = app.Documents[i];
    if (doc.Type == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisDocumentTypes.visTypeStencil)
    {
         //doc.Name has the filename you are looking for
    }
}
```